# Grayscale Image Filtration

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale

I need to make a filter for an grayscale image which paints 130-135 to blue, 140-145 to red in grayscale. Any idea how? Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import cv2

original=cv2.imread('D:/download.jfif')

gray=cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


fig, axes= plt.subplots(1,2)
ax=axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(original)
ax[0].set_title("Original")
ax[1].imshow(gray, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1].set_title("Grayscale")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

plt.hist(gray,bins=256)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
output = original.copy() # or...
#output = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

output[(gray >= 130) & (gray <= 135)] = (255, 0, 0) # blue (BGR)
output[(gray >= 140) & (gray <= 145)] = (0, 0, 255) # red (BGR)
```

Comment: Oh just noticed something, this code filters the image in RGB, i need to filter it in grayscale. Is it possible to grayscale an image with red and blue colors?

Comment: I don't understand the question. can you give an example

Comment: Think of a grayscale image with all gray, and areas between 130-135 are shown in blue and 140-145 are shown in red.
What i mean is output should be grayscale.

Comment: do you mean output should be original in gray *with selected colors overlaid*? use the commented out line in my code.

Comment: Yess i have done it, thank you so much for your assistance. :)